# Concat observables reusing the previous results

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Imagine I have 3 functions, taking some arguments and returning an observable. Logic would be (all would be a result of something async):

1. Get a cat.
2. Pet the cat.
3. Get food for the cat based on it's mood after petting it.

Sample code:

```
function getCat(): Observable<Cat> {
  return Observable.of({ name: 'Larry' }) 
}

function petCat(cat: Cat): Observable<Mood> {
  return Observable.of(Mood.HAPPY)
}

function getFood(cat: Cat, mood: Mood): Observable<Food> {
  return Observable.of({ type: 'fish' })
}
```

1. I would like to end up with an Observable that's equivalent with this:

   `Observable.from([{ name: 'Larry' }, Mood.HAPPY, { type: 'fish' }])`
2. I would like the functions to be invoked in sequence (obviously from the parameter signatures)
3. I would not like to delay the individual emits, in the final observable I'd like to get the results as soon as they arrive.

I could get it working with something like this:

```
function perform() {
  return getCat().pipe(
    mergeMap((cat) => concat(
        of(cat),
        petCat(cat).pipe(
          mergeMap((mood) => concat(
            of(mood),
            getFood(cat, mood)
          ))
        )
      )
    ),
  )
}
```

**Question is**, is there a better, more readable way of doing this (let's say I would have 5 of these that I would like to chain)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
getCat()
.pipe(
   switchMap(cat => petCat(cat).pipe(map(mood => ({cat, mood})))),
   switchMap(({cat, mood}) => getFood(cat, mood))
)
```

The whole idea is to use `switchMap` to *switch* from the source Observable to the Observable returned by the function passed to `switchMap` as parameter.

Maybe worth of mentioning is the use of `map` chained into the pipe of the first `switchMap`. That `map` operator makes sure that we keep `cat` as part of the parameters we pass the second, and last, `switchMap`.

**UPDATE after comment**
If the function `perform` has to emit all the 3 elements emitted by the 3 functions, then you may try something like the following

```
function perform() {
   return getCat()
          .pipe(
             switchMap(cat => petCat(cat).pipe(map(mood => ({cat, mood})))),
             switchMap(({cat, mood}) => getFood(cat, mood).pipe(map(food => ({cat, mood, food}))))
          )
}
```

Comment: Hey @Picci, thanks for the answer. The problem with this answer, is that it will only emit the last value in the returned observable.

Comment: What would you expect to get as result? The simulating functions you propose just emit 1 element. In the real case do you expect any of the Observables actually emit more than 1 value?

Comment: I mean the final `perform()` function. It emits all 3 elements from the 3 functions in a single observable.